# django: convert request param into list of strings

Tags: python, django

With a request parameter like this:

```
filter_tiles=01,21,30
```

How do I convert the value into list of strings in Django?

I used this:

```
filter_tiles = filter(len, map(str, request.POST.get('filter_tiles', '').split(',')))
```

Not liking it though.

Comment: What are you not liking in it? It is quite efficient

Comment: Have you done a `print data.get('filter_tiles', '').split(',')` just to see what is there?

Comment: @JamesR: That does not work for corner cases like `''.split(',')` or `'a,'.split(',')`. But that `map(str, x)` is really unnecessary. Thanks. I have expected some builtin support though.

Comment: is your data already a string? if so wouldn't mapping str be unecessary? could you post your data using the same `name` attributes? that way i belive you could use `getlist` method

Comment: @clime my question was just to see what the data is, not to actually use it. I'm still trying to understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: @jamesr: it is a POST parameter. The value comes to me as a string.

Comment: @dm03514: I think getlist is the answer! Gonna try that out.

Comment: @dm03514: Oh now I finally understand that note _could you post your data using the same name attributes?_ :) because at the moment it just returns ['01,21,30']. There would need to be multiple parameters named `filter_tile` in the request each with one value, right? Well I would prefer keeping it as one param. But thanks I wasn't aware of that possibility.

Comment: @karthikr: I don't like it because I expect there to be something that can convert GET/POST params into python types.

Answer (score -1):

see code below:

```
import urlparse
urlparse.parse_qs('filter_tiles=01,21,30')
```

`{'filter_tiles': ['01,21,30']}` #output

Now you can access it like any other dict.